# fluent NHibernate automapping

Tags: collections, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many, relationship, automapping

Please, how can I do map a property of type one-to-many in fluent NHibernate through AutoMapping?

My entities are mapped like down there:
[image]

Comment: you have to provide more detail than that: what happens when you try to automap your entities? how do your entities look (code)? what exactly is the problem (error message / undesired behaviour)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

- `TipoContato` should have `IList<Contato>` (or `ICollection<Contato>`) property
- or `Contato` should have `TipoContato` property

Both ways automapping should handle everything correctly, assuming that you either change the name of column with foreign key in `Contacto` table to `TipoContacto_id` or provide your own foreign key naming convention to skip the default underscore - see more about conventions on [Fluent NHibernate manual](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions#ForeignKeyConvention).

If you want to have different relation in object model, i.e. two-way, you'll need to define it manually in [automapping override](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Overrides) using `HasMany` with `Inverse` on `TipoContato` side and `References` on `Contato` side.

Anyway, if you have modelled your database first, it can be harder to use automapping and it will probably need a lot of overrides. You should either make your object model first and use automapping, or make your database first and prepare mappings manually.